# Please give information about this insects

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I took this photo of a small insect which I found near to my house (Maharashtra state, India). What insect is this?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and earn your first badge. Also, you have to tell us where and when this photo was taken in order to increase the chances of identifying this insect.

Comment: It is definitely a member of Membracidae. A treehopper. Order Hemiptera.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like an insect belonging to the family [Cicadidae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicadidae). Further information is needed to identify this cicada species.

Comment: @SachinPrabhu I'm not sure about my answer, where did you find the insect exactly?

Comment: In India state Maharashtra where

Comment: This isn't a Cicada: it's a treehopper (family Membracidae) but not knowing the Indian fauna of the family I can't go any deeper.